# Data driven real time graph

Tags: javascript, python, graph

I want to create a node based graph that's data driven and works in real time. The data is received at random time intervals so polling wont work. I issue the data in the form of a stream of JSON object.
I searched and went through a lot of libraries but none of them would be able to solve the problem because the data arrives faster than the library can process it. Sometimes, the rate goes as high as 70 events per second which makes the current libraries such as [VivaGraphJS](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS) and [Arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/) unusable.
There are a lot of libraries for creating realtime charts but I couldn't find any for node based graphs.
Could any of you suggest a library that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library? Although it is not specifically graph-based (it is a data driven library), it is useful to display information and there are many apps working with graphs.

Maybe it can help to process your data. But its just an idea, I haven't tried with the stream frequency you are dealing.

See here some beautiful examples when displaying graph data:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/929623

http://redotheweb.com/CodeFlower/

Comment: I went through D3 and thought of using it. I didn't find any dynamic graphs implemented with it which is why I'm not sure about it. It'd be great if someone can give me a fitting solution. :)